# fill a select html with mysql table rows

Tags: mysql, html, forms, servlets

I'm writting a web app, I'm doing a html form with javascript to validate the data, I'm using a servlet to insert the data in a DB, but I need, when the form load, fill a select in the html form with the rows of a table in a MySql DB, I think I have to make a query in a ResultSet and then fill the select in the html form with this info, and then use the HttpServletResponse, but I have no idea how to make this

Comment: So you want to pre-fill a form using data from MySQL?

Comment: Yes, I need to fill a select, specifically I need fill a select with a list of Countries, but this countries are in the mysql table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP to access the database and then put it into the form. Something like this:

```
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id='$id'");

 $info = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 $name = $info['name'];
 $email = $info['email'];
 $anotherField = $info['another_field'];
```

In this, the info array has all of the database data in it of the id. But of course you would change the values and stuff. Change table_name to the table name, and if you are going to do something in the URL like `?id=373384` or something, then this will work. (I would assume you are doing it this way.) But, if it isn't 'id', just change *WHERE id='$id'* to what is in the database to identify a line.

*$info['name'];* would be the "name" column in your table. But, you can change 'name' and stuff to what you have in your database.

Here is the form code to pre-fill it with data:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>" />
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $email ?>" />
<!--etc...-->
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

You would need to change a lot of this, but I'm sure you get the point of it. :)

*Note: This is not a simple copy+paste script. You will have to do a lot of charing because I don't know what your table values are and stuff.*

If you have any questions, please do ask.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed you are probably using jsp or something. I'll have to delete my answer then because I don't know jsp or whatever you're using.

Comment: No problem! :) If you have any questions about it, I am here to help.